# Normalization of images containing complex numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix, normalization, complex-numbers

In MATLAB, I have an image which contains complex numbers. I would like to normalize the matrix in order to make the values lie between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but suppose you would like to do it for real numbers:

M = 10*rand(5)-5;
M_normalized = (M-min(M(:)))/(max(M(:))-min(M(:)))

Make sure to check but in general it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use the [abs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html) function to convert from imaginary to real numbers.  Then use @DennisJaheruddin 's answer to scale to the correct range

Answer (score 0):

First, where did the complex numbers come from, and why do you need to normalize the image?

It is a rare thing to have a complex image, unless it is a Fourier transform of some other image. So unless you have expected to get a complex image, you may want to check for bugs.

If you need to normalize for the purpose of displaying the image with `imshow`, then you may want to display its magnitude and phase instead. You can use the `abs` function to get the magnitude, and the `angle` function to get the phase.